# CSS styling radio input when checked

Tags: html, css

I have styled the following radio buttons so that the actual radio is `display:none` and the label is an `inline-block` with a `background-color`.

I am struggling to find how to show a different background colour on the checked radio button.

Obviously its a simple thing that I am missing:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
label + checked {
  background-color: #ffcb00;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 4vw;
  line-height: 4vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
}
label {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 4vw;
  line-height: 4vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="100" checked />
  <b>&#163;100</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="250" />
  <b>&#163;250</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="500" />
  <b>&#163;500</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="1000" />
  <b>&#163;1,000</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="amount" value="1500" />
  <b>&#163;1,500</b>
</label>

<br>

<br>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="30" checked />
  <b>30 days</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="60" />
  <b>60 days</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="90" />
  <b>90 days</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="180" />
  <b>180 days</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="360" />
  <b>360 days</b>
</label>
```

Comment: You would need to change your HTML structure. Is that an option?

Comment: Probably not without messing my javascript, but what do you suggest?

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6nmn212f/) @J.Ayo. The HTML is still not complete and so if you try to select other radio buttons, it won't show any change.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `label` is the parent of the `input[type="checkbox"]` you can't select it directly in CSS. One option of fixing this would be the following. Add an extra `div` to the `label` (`.background` in my example) and use that to change the background color. Of course there are many more options to fix this, but this is probably the simplest one.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.background{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .background{
  background-color: #ffcb00;  
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 4vw;
  line-height: 4vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
}

label *{
  
  position: relative;

}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="30"  />
  <div class="background"></div>
  <b>30 days</b>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="term" value="30" checked />
  <div class="background"></div>
  <b>30 days</b>
</label>
```

Comment: this works exactly how I want in the snippet. But when I try and use it on my page, it doesn't! Can't see why as there is no other CSS I can see that would interfere!

Comment: @J.Ayo can you give me a link to your site, or a representing fiddle so I can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `+` selector incorrectly. `a + b` means select any element `b` immediately following an `a`, for example:

```
<a></a>
<b></b>
```

By changing your HTML so that labels immediately follow radio buttons, we're able to use the pseudo-selector `:checked` to detect when a radio button is checked and style the label appropriately.

Note that I also added `for` attributes to your labels and `id`s to the radio buttons to create an association between the two.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #ffcb00;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 4vw;
  line-height: 4vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
}
label {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 4vw;
  line-height: 4vw;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="amount" id="amount1" value="100" />
<label for="amount1">&#163;100</label>

<input type="radio" name="amount" id="amount2" value="250" />
<label for="amount2">&#163;250</label>
```